# Why do my paypal ipn validations always return INVALID?

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I am using a PHP class that I have created based on the sample code from the paypal website.  I am also using this with CodeIgniter.  I test the IPN listener with the IPN simulator.  My emails are sent, so I know it is being accessed.  The problem is that I always get a response of INVALID and I have no idea why.  This is my first time integrating PayPal within one of my sites.  What could be causing this problem?

Here is my class:

```
<?php

class Paypal {

    public $sandbox = false;
    private $_url;
    public $verified = false;
    public $fields = array();
    public $post_fields = array();
    public $result;

    public function __construct($params = array()){

        $this->sandbox = (isset($params['sandbox'])) ? $params['sandbox'] : false;

        $this->_url = ($this->sandbox) ? 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' : 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';

    }

    public function run(){

        $this->verified = false;

        // STEP 1: read POST data
        // Reading POSTed data directly from $_POST causes serialization issues with array data in the POST.
        // Instead, read raw POST data from the input stream.
        $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);

        foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {

          $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);

          if (count($keyval) == 2)

            $this->post_fields[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);

        }

        // read the IPN message sent from PayPal and prepend 'cmd=_notify-validate'
        $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

        if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {

          $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;

        }

        foreach ($this->post_fields as $key => $value) {

          if ($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {

            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));

          } else {

            $value = urlencode($value);

          }

          $req .= "&$key=$value";

        }

        // Step 2: POST IPN data back to PayPal to validate
        $ch = curl_init($this->_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
        // In wamp-like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
        // please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set
        // the directory path of the certificate as shown below:
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, FCPATH.'cacert.pem');
        if ( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
          // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
          curl_close($ch);
          die('curl did not work<br>'.FCPATH.'cacert.pem');
        }
        curl_close($ch);

        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

            $this->verified = true;            

        }

        $this->result = $res;

    }
```

Here is my CI Controller:

```
function paypalipn(){

        $this->load->model('subscription');
        $this->load->library('paypal', array('sandbox' => true));;

        $this->paypal->run();

        $fields = $this->paypal->post_fields;

        if($this->paypal->verified){

            $data = array(
                'user_id' => $fields['buyer_id'],
                'txn_id' => $fields['txn_id'],
                'payment_gross' => $fields['mc_gross'],
                'currency_code' => $fields['mc_currency'],
                'payer_email' => $fields['payer_email'],
                'plan_id' => $fields['item_number'],
                'payment_status' => $fields['payment_status']
            );

            $this->subscription->create_payment($data);

        }

        $this->load->library('email');

        $this->email->to('*******@gmail.com');
        $this->email->from('**************');
        $this->email->subject('PayPal IPN');
        $this->email->message($this->paypal->result."\nAmount: ".$fields['mc_gross']."\nCurrency: ".$fields['mc_currency']."\nUser ID: ".$fields['buyer_id']);

        $this->email->send();

    }
```

All of the fields are blank in the email message and $this->paypal->result always returns "INVALID".  Anybody have any ideas?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your Paypal class looks solid to me and seems to be nearly identical the the working code I use. Must be some other issue and SSL is the first place to look. Does SSL actually work on your site and is 'cacert.pem' the certificate you use for the site? Without a verified https connection PayPal will always return INVALID.

Comment: Look in your logs on Paypal to see what response you are getting - I'd debug your cUrl further to see if anything is blocking your request.

Comment: I did some debugging and I see that $raw_post_data is always empty.  Could this be causing the issue?  How could I fix this?

Comment: You need to inform paypal where to send the IPN result.
if CSRF is enabled, this will fail. The result is found in $_POST array and not $this->input->post(). You are not sending any legit headers to paypal for this to pass. re-read the docs and find out what headers need to be sent.

Comment: is `$this->subscription->create_payment($data);` working? most probably all the code inside `if($this->paypal->verified){}` should fail since verified is false. But emails are sent. Can you post what is the output of `curl_exec($ch)` in the first place?

Comment: Any reason you are not using PayPal's PHP SDK? I have found it much easier to work with. On a side note, I have had trouble with PayPal's raw data, so I wrote this regex to parse it the PHP way: https://gist.github.com/hypeJunction/913f07c5fc4f2542a0aa

Answer (score 0):

In your CI controller if you have written your code like this:

```
function paypalipn(){

        $this->load->model('subscription');
        $this->load->library('paypal', array('sandbox' => true));;

        $this->paypal->run();

        $fields = $this->paypal->post_fields;

        if($this->paypal->verified){

            $data = array(
                'user_id' => $fields['buyer_id'],
                'txn_id' => $fields['txn_id'],
                'payment_gross' => $fields['mc_gross'],
                'currency_code' => $fields['mc_currency'],
                'payer_email' => $fields['payer_email'],
                'plan_id' => $fields['item_number'],
                'payment_status' => $fields['payment_status']
            );

            $this->subscription->create_payment($data);
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->to('*******@gmail.com');
        $this->email->from('**************');
        $this->email->subject('PayPal IPN');
        $this->email->message($this->paypal->result."\nAmount: ".$fields['mc_gross']."\nCurrency: ".$fields['mc_currency']."\nUser ID: ".$fields['buyer_id']);
        $this->email->send();
        }
    }
```

OR if you have stopped the script in case the if statement failed

```
if($this->paypal->verified){

            $data = array(
                'user_id' => $fields['buyer_id'],
                'txn_id' => $fields['txn_id'],
                'payment_gross' => $fields['mc_gross'],
                'currency_code' => $fields['mc_currency'],
                'payer_email' => $fields['payer_email'],
                'plan_id' => $fields['item_number'],
                'payment_status' => $fields['payment_status']
            );

            $this->subscription->create_payment($data);
} else {
exit("We are sad to inform you that verification FAILED. Bye!");
}
```

you would not receive any email. The issue is in `public function run()` in your paypal class and this is most probably the failing part.

```
       if ( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
          curl_close($ch);
          die('curl did not work<br>'.FCPATH.'cacert.pem');
        }
        curl_close($ch);
       if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {   
            $this->verified = true;                
        }
```

Try re-writing it like this

```
       $res=curl_exec($ch); // define $res
       if($res==null){  // check if $res is null
            exit('curl did not work<br>'.FCPATH.'cacert.pem');
        }
       curl_close($ch);
       if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") === 0) {   
            $this->verified = true;                
       }
```

Regarding the last 3 lines where `strcmp()` is used, and based on a user [comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php#113364) in `strcmp()` documentation.

> - *strcmp() will return NULL on failure.*
> - *This has the side effect of equating to a match when using an equals comparison (==).*
> - *Instead, you may wish to test matches using the identical comparison (===), which should not catch a NULL return.*

What does the above mean? In a small example.

```
if(null==0) {
echo "1";
}
if(null===0) {
echo "2";
}
```

The above example will only output [=> 1](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5579b7297d17eabd3f972cfa25b7b531208c23a3) which in your case that means that if `strcmp()` fails you will have set `verified` to `true` which is not correct.